# How to process an html element containing a template text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Usually I use the following form of code to display html elements with their data:

```
<div id="parent">
  <span>loading...</span>
</div>

<script>
  var data="im data";
  $("#parent").html(`<span>${data}</span>`);
</script>
```

But it is very inconvenient I have to write the span element twice and it will be very inconvenient if there are elements that need to be changed, so I want to fetch the element first instead of writing it back.

So I want to fetch the element first instead of writing it back,
and code look like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <span>${data}</span>
</div>

<script>
  var data="im data";

  $("#parent").html($("#parent").html());

  // it displayed ${data} not im data
</script>
```

But it doesn't produce as I expected.

**Problem SOLVED here example, Thankyou for accepted answer Carsten Massmann**

```js
const data={id:"1",name:"john doe"};
const datas=[
  {id:"1",name:"hasan"},
  {id:"2",name:"salim"}
];

passData($("#parent"),data);
passDatas($("#parent2"),datas);
//usage

 function passDatas(parent,data){
    if(parent.data("_html_temp")==undefined){
        parent.data("_html_temp",parent.html());
    }

    parent.html("");
    data.forEach((obj)=>{
      parent.append(parent.data("_html_temp").replace(/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g,(_,n)=>obj[n]));
    })
  }
  
  function passData(parent,data){
    if(parent.data("_html_temp")==undefined){
        parent.data("_html_temp",parent.html());
    }
    parent.html(parent.data("_html_temp").replace(/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g,(_,n)=>data[n]));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Single Object
<div id="parent">
   <div>
    <span>id:${id}</span>
    <span>name:${name}</span>
   </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

Array Object
<div id="parent2">
   <div>
    <span>id:${id}</span>
    <span>name:${name}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain more about what you need with a proper example.

Comment: i have included proper example i can't possibly write full code here

Comment: If you are trying to update the `<span>` tag, why not write: `$("#parent span").html(data);`? Or just give the `<span>` an ID and target it directly?

Comment: ```
<span>${data}</span>
``` i need this to be excuted first like the first  code before it replacing current element

Comment: i want use that like JSX, when im getting  array data json  is just passing data to it, so is not possible give them id one by one

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. This is not JSX. Where is the array or JSON? You should simplify your question. Right now it is too vague.

Comment: Why not just use the `js` script to replace the text with what you want in that place. Something like `var data = "im data";` 
`var newHTML = $("#parent").html().replace(/\$\{data\}/g, data);`
`$("#parent").html(newHTML);`

Comment: that easy to say that if data is just like variable with single value, the realty is 
element look like this
`
<div>
  <span>${data.name}</span>
  <span>${data.id}</span>
</div>
`
and data look like this


`{data:[{id:1,"name":"steve"}],[{id:2,"name":"steve2"}],[{id:3,"name":"steve3"}]}`

Comment: @MHASANUDDINWebDeveloperBen are you using reactjs or normal html with jquery ?

Comment: im not give reactjs tags on myquestion, so that mean im use normal html with jquery,

Comment: then why you want your syntax to be like jsx ? In normal Javascript you can use your variable i template string usin backticks instead of single quote or double quote, here it is `

Comment: if i write the back tick twice here it wont be shown to you, try it your self like other quotes, or learn about this here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp

Comment: seem you not mentioned my question before

Comment: i have modified my answer, added the append system in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of setting up a *very simple* templating engine:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span>This is ${data}. And here it is again: "${data}"!</span>
And here is stuff outside the span element: ${other}
</div>
<script>
  const D={data:"the actual content",other:"another value"};
  $("#parent").html($("#parent").html().replace(/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g,(_,n)=>D[n]));
</script>
```

However, it is not capable of nesting `${...}` elements and can only reference simple values from a given object `D`.

The action is mainly done by a `.replace` callback function. The second argument `n` of that function contains the content of the first search group and this is then used to look up the actual content from `D`.

There is **another way** of doing it using `eval()`, although this is usually *shunned* by the JavaScript programming community for "security reasons". `eval()` will evaluate *everything* it is given as an argument, so this *might* incriminate the security and integrity of your page. But by using this technique you are tapping into the full power of the JavaScript interpreter: You can now also process nested template structures. Make up you own mind about it.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span>This is ${data}. And here it is again: "${data}"!</span>
And here is stuff outside the span element: ${other} 
and even a little calculation: ${`${other}: 2+2=${2+2}`}.
</div>
<script>
  const data="the actual content",other="another value";
  $("#parent").html(eval("`"+$("#parent").html()+"`"));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this actually what i want

Comment: awesome work!!, i dont know why other people keep confusing with myquestion

Comment: may I ask you where will you apply this replace function ? i think this function is not for normal use, its only for scraping and manipulating html document

Comment: I am simply applying the standard `String.prototype.replace()` method on the HTML string of the `#parent` element. The manipulated string is then returned and used in a `$("#parent").html(...)` call to replace the original content.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are writing

```
<div id="parent">
  <span>${data}</span>
</div>
```

in your html file which will show as normal text

if you want to show some data in the span instead of `${data}`

you can use

```
<script>
var data="im data";

$("#parent span").text(data);

// it will display im data
</script>
```

and if you want to fetch the html first then use

```
var data = $("#parent").html(); // it will fetch <span>im data</span>
var dataOnly = $("parent span").text(); // it will fetch im data

$("#parent").html(data); // it will output the same
$("#parent").text(dataOnly); //it will make your html <div id="parent">im data</div>

// if you want to change the data inside span the try
$("#parent span").text("you custom text"); // to show text in the span
$("#parent").html("you custom html"); // to change the html of the parent div
```

if you want to add more data in your parent div then

```
var span = $('<span />').html('new data');
$("#parent").append(span);
```

i think this will help to understand how jquery works